# Required Input() parameter still emits "has no initializer" error

Tags: angular, typescript

I like all the new null safety features of TypeScript, but sometimes I am not sure how to treat certain cases.
One scenario I often face is the following:

Lets say I have a component with an @Input() parameter.
This parameter is required (introduced in Angular 16), like:

```
@Input({ required: true }) myInput1: string;
```

However, typescript emits an error here:

```
Property 'myInput1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
```

I don't think this error is necessary, because I will force the caller of my component to pass an input parameter. Its required for a reason.

However, none of the solutions I like.

- Disabling strictPropertyInitialization would not be nice, because I
  still want the null safety.
- Marking the property as nullable via the ?-Operator is also not nice, because the property  is not nullable. It has to be set. Its required.
- Adding the undefined to the possible types is also not good, because of the same reason.
- Initializing the value with a default value is also not nice, because this value would be wrong. However, this is still my favorite.

Is there any other solution you could recommend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go for this is to use the non-null assertion operator `!`.

```
@Input({ required: true }) myInput1!: string;
```